# Access denied on Password Recovery page

Tags: users

I tried to customize the "password recovery" page under Drupal 7, based on this tutorial : http://www.absolutecross.com/tutorials/drupal/theming-the-user-account-page-in-drupal. 
I did so for the register and edit page, and it works ok.

However, for this page, I run into a problem. When the page "/user/pass" (is that the standard url by the way ?) is called, I ran into an access denied page.

I browse through the permissions : nothing in there to allow/deny access to this page. I also use loginToboggan, disabled it for a while, to no avail.

Any idea of what I could I have overlooked ? I am lost...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password recovery page is at "/user/password", not "/user/pass".

I also get an Access Denied when visiting "/user/pass" on one of my sites, whether I'm logged in or not, so I think you can assume this is the expected behaviour for that particular path.

Comment: Hello Clive, 

Of course, I tested with "password" also, but your hint was useful,so I investigated a little more. 

I had several problems, but one of them was due a bad naming of my template, not following the right convention. I used  "page--user--pass.tpl.php" and I should have used "page--user-password.tpl.php" instead. 
Thanks for putting me on the right path !